# SQLALchemy lazy compile classes

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

i haven't found solution for this. Problem in very load compile (40 sec)
I have:

- more then 1200 classes
- 300 enums
- and some custom primitive classes for working
- 7 levels of polymorphic inherits
- some itself relationship, may one-to-many and many-to-many in one class to itself
- parents and childs may have somenamed relationship to one table

I undestand, that's big project, but in develop i need load ~100 classes.
Do the product exists that can do it or i need to create custom class map and custom factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For perform this task i create only classes with inheritance and primary keys.

Steps is:

1) After that i wrote function who take one argument(class name) check if it already not loaded and create attributes, foreign_keys and relationship, somethink like `class.attrib=Column(String)`

2) Override definition `__new__` for creating classes, `__getattr__` for queries and maybe need `__setattr__`, i don't know

```
  def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
    if cls.__name__ not in sl_loaded_classes: sl_load_function(cls.__name__)
    return super(MyCLA,cls).__new__(cls)

  def __getattr__(self,attr):
    if "MyClass" not in sl_loaded_classes: sl_load_function("NameType")
    if False: pass
    elif attr=="relation" and "RelatedClass" not in sl_loaded_classes:
      sl_load_function("RelatedClass")
      for sl_class in gc.get_objects():
        if isinstance(sl_class,self.__class__):
          config.session.refresh(sl_class)
    else: return config.Base.__getattr__(self, attr)
    return getattr(self,attr)
```

And now it worked, not pefect (i can't deleted object, before load related classes), but it in process